# Trying to removeEventListener but its not working. Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, keydown, removeeventlistener

I am trying to remove this event listener that I added and it doesn't remove. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any thoughts is greatly appreciated? My code is below.

```
headerElement.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => onHeaderKeyDown(parentElement, columnApi, evt));
headerElement.removeEventListener('keydown', (evt) => onHeaderKeyDown(parentElement, columnApi, evt));
```

Comment: hello, working with anonymous fonctions to remove event listener, will not handle the same reference of the event to be removed, so to fix that you should save the reference of the functions in a variable/constants, then remove the event listener with the same reference (variable/constant), why ? because removing listeners will always look for the same used event name and the same event handler reference

Comment: so here is my suggestion: 
`const handlerRef = (evt) => onHeaderKeyDown(parentElement, columnApi, evt);
headerElement.addEventListener('keydown', handlerRef);
headerElement.removeEventListener('keydown', handlerRef);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you

```
headerElement.addEventListener('keydown', 
  (evt) => onHeaderKeyDown(parentElement, columnApi, evt));
headerElement.removeEventListener('keydown', 
  (evt) => onHeaderKeyDown(parentElement, columnApi, evt));
```

you're actually creating two handlers.

`((evt) => doSomething()) === ((evt) => doSomething())` is false. `removeEventListener` uses equality against handlers that have previously been added to decide which handler should be removed.

So first you are adding one handler, then trying to remove one that was never added in the first place. Net result is that the added handler is not removed.

If instead, you store the added handler in a variable, then remove the same one, all will be good:

```
const handler = (evt) => onHeaderKeyDown(parentElement, columnApi, evt)
headerElement.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
headerElement.removeEventListener('keydown', handler);
```